# Provisioning profile doesn't match the entitlements file's value for the com.apple.security.application-groups entitlement

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine, provisioning-profile

I'm trying to deploy compile my application build with Unity with Xcode. But I got the error :

> Provisioning profile "iOS Team Provisioning Profile: >com.name.of.my.site" doesn't match the entitlements file's value
>   for the com.apple.security.application-groups entitlement.

In the provisioning file I have no value for the security group :

```
    <array>
    </array>
    <key>com.apple.developer.ubiquity-container-identifiers</key>
    <array>
    </array>
    <key>com.apple.security.application-groups</key>
    <array>
    </array>
    <key>com.apple.developer.team-identifier</key>
    <string>myidhere</string>
    <key>aps-environment</key>
    <string>development</string>
```

Please, how could I correct it ? This is the first time I got this error. I didn't activate app group in my developer console, because, till now I didn't have to activate it.
Please could you help me ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Your entitlement file contains this key `com.apple.security.application-groups` , Check your app id has those capabilities?

Go to developer apple account, check your identifier details and you can see all the capabilities that support your app id. `com.apple.security.application-groups` this contains groups capability add group inside your app id will fix your issue.

Comment: I have no idea what any of that means. These tools are super obscure :(

Comment: it means you need to select your identifier, edit the detail of App Groups to use your new group (register it first)